# Sum 3D matrix cuda

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I need to do calculation like: A[x][y] = sum{from z=0 till z=n}{B[x][y][z]+C[x][y][z]}, where matrix A has dimensions [height][width] and matrix B,C has dimensions [height][width][n].

Values are mapped to memory with something like:

```
index = 0;
for (z = 0; z<n; ++z)
    for(y = 0; y<width; ++y)
        for(x = 0; x<height; ++x) {
            matrix[index] = value;
            index++;
        }
```

Q1: is this Cuda kernel ok?

```
idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

for(z=0; z<n; z++){
    A[idx*width+idy] += B[idx*width+idy+z*width*height] + C[idx*width+idy+z*width*height];
}
```

Q2: Is this faster way to do the calculation?

```
idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
idy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
idz = blockIdx.z*blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

int  stride_x = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
int  stride_y = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;
int  stride_z = blockDim.z * gridDim.z;

while ( idx < height && idy < width && idz < n ) {
    atomicAdd( &(A[idx*width+idy]), B[idx*width+idy+idz*width*height] + C[idx*width+idy+idz*width*height] );
    idx += stride_x;
    idy += stride_y;
    idz += stride_z;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First kernel is ok. But we have not coalesced access to matrix `B` and `C`.

As for second kernel function. You have data racing cause not only one thread has an an ability to write in `A[idx*width+idy]` addres. You need in additional synchronization like `AttomicAdd`

As for general question:
I think that experiments show that it is better. It's depends on typical matrix sizes that you have. Remember that maximum thread block size on Fermi < 1024 and if matrices have large size you gem many thread blocks. Usually it's slower (to have many thread blocks).

Comment: good point with data racing, thx :)
when I add atomic function the code form Q2 will do exactly the same as code in Q1?
my main goal is speed so I am looking for fastest solution.

Comment: "experiments show that it is better", it is better tu use atomic functions? or not use it?

Comment: Usually synchronization point decreases performance noticeably. It's closely depends on count of warps executed in parallel in one period of time. Better to use shared memory to store intermediate results. In shared memory synchronization is OK but I prefer avoid it in global memory.

Answer (score 2):

Real simple in [ArrayFire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/group__sumprod__mat.htm):

```
array A = randu(nx,ny,nz);
array B = sum(A,2); // sum along 3rd dimension
print(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Test it with matrices where you know the answer

Remark: You might have problems when using very large matrices. Use a while loop with appropriate increments. Cuda by Example is as usual the reference book.

An example for implementing a nested loop can be found here: [For nested loops with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921873/for-nested-loops-with-cuda). There a while loop is implemented.

marina.k is right about the race condition. That would favor approach one, as atomic operations tend to slow down the code.

Comment: Maximum dimensionality of thread block = 3, Maximum dimensionality of grid of thread blocks = 2 (for CC < 2), =3 (for CC >= 2). so I think there is no problem. I have large matrices but do not see the problem.

Comment: you ment: `if ( idx >= height || idy >= width || idz  >= n ) return;` ?

Comment: Yes but you need not an if but a while. Suppose you have 1024 kernels but your matrix has size 2048 then you will not reach all the indices.